# Как достать информацию из торрент файла?

Tags: php, torrent

Как достать информацию из торрент файла? Такую как: кол-во сидеров, личеров, а также размер.

Comment: [Было][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/46012/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Я смотрел это, мне это не нужно. Конкретно как это вытащить?

Answer (score 1):

> В Торрент-файле, (он же файл метаданных),  находится вся информация по файлу (или файлам), участвующему в раздаче. Без него по протоколу Bittorent скачать ничего не удастся. В общем виде структуру файла метаданных можно разделить на три составляющие.
>
> Внутренности torrent-файла – это bencoding-данные. Формат файла позволяет хранить следующие типы данных: байт-строки, числа, списки и директивы.
>
> В общем виде формат записи строковых данных выглядит так:
>
> СТРОКИ
>
> `<длина строки>:<строка>`. Пример: 5:xakep
>
> Числа
>
> `<ключ i><число><ключ e>`. Пример: i31337e
>
> Списки
>
> `<ключ l><bencoding данные><ключ e>`. Пример: l5:xakep5:lamere
>
> Директивы
>
> `<ключ d><строка bencoding><элемент bencoding><ключ e>`. Пример: d5:coder6:spidere (Coder => spider)`
>
> В спецификации структуры файла метаданных есть несколько предопределенных директив:
>
> - info – директива для описания свойств файлов. В зависимости от типа торрент-файла (обычный – один файл или смешанный – несколько файлов) эта директива применяется по-разному. В директиву входят: piece length – длина сегмента файла; pieces – хэш сумма сегмента, полученная по алгоритму SHA1. Разницу применения директивы для обычного и смешанного режимов смотри в таблице 2;
> - announce – анонс URL;
> - announce list – список, содержащий несколько announce URL;
> - create date – дата создания torrent файла в формате Unix-time;
> - comment – комментарий от создателя торрент-файла;
> - created by – название и версия программы, в которой был создан torrent-файл.

[Источник](http://www.xakep.ru/magazine/xa/114/096/1.asp).

Comment: А вот количеств сидеров и личеров, а также их ip-адресов, номеров телефонов и банковских счетов там нет :)

Comment: @ХэшКод Спасибо за правку, поспешил.

Comment: Открой подходящим редактором (любой hex, блокнот, wordpad, Notepade++) и посмотри. Перечисленная информация находися в первой строке :)

Answer (score 0):

Нужнен анализатор торрент-формата bencode, что-то вроде [такого](http://janych.selfip.com/my/#TorrentFilesAnalizer). Сделать подобное на PHP можно с помощью [File_Bittorrent2](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Bittorrent2/).